# How do I implement bilingual sentence alignment for English and Japanese texts in Python and export them to XLSX?

Tags: python, translation

I am working on a project that requires aligning bilingual texts at the sentence level between English and Japanese, and I need to export the alignment results to an XLSX file or a similar format. My goal is to automate this process so that given any English text and its corresponding Japanese text, I can generate a spreadsheet file containing the aligned sentences in two languages.

aligning bilingual texts at the sentence level between English and Japanese, and I need to export the alignment results to an XLSX file or a similar format